# Geph4-client is not connecting in vpn-mode in linux manjaro

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, vpn, arch, great-firewall-of-china

The geph4-client could not connect in vpn mode but it connects in no-vpn mode and the proxy is working.
geph version: `geph4-client 4.7.12`

command: `sudo geph4-client connect --override-connect [key]@[servers-ip:17814] --vpn-mode tun-route`

command `[geph4client INFO]: geph4-client v4.7.12 starting...`
`[geph4client::connect INFO]: connect mode starting: exit = None, force_protocol = None, use_bridges = false`
`[geph4client::connect::dns DEBG]: DNS loop started`

`[geph4client::connect::socks5 DEBG]: socks5 started`

`[geph4client::connect DEBG]: gonna construct the tunnel`

`[geph4client::connect::vpn INFO]: VPN task about to get client IP...`

`[geph4client::connect::vpn::linux_routing DEBG]: waiting for tunnel to connect...`

`[geph4client::connect::tunnel::tunnel_actor INFO]: TUNNEL_ACTOR MAIN LOOP!`

`[geph4client::connect::tunnel::tunnel_actor INFO]: RECV-CONN [server-ip]:17814 / PROT obfsudp-1`

`[geph4client::config DEBG]: lockcount incr 0`

`[geph4client::connect::vpn INFO]: VPN task initializing IP to 0.0.48.57`

`RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory`

`RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory`

`iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.`

`iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.`

`ip6tables: Bad rule (does a matching rule exist in that chain?).`

`ip6tables: No chain/target/match by that name.`

i tried tun-noroute option instaed of tun-route but when trying to connect using curl --interface tun-geph it take forever to answer